# Can a .NET program compiled on 32bit OS be run on 64bit Linux System under mono without any issues?

Tags: .net, linux, mono, crash, 64-bit

I wrote a program on Windows 7 32bit system and test running it on 64bit linux system on another machine. It is showing runtime issues just as it follows. However, we even updated our MONO to the latest stable release.

```
======= Backtrace: =========                                                                         
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x73476)[0x7f40404ca476]                                                           
/usr/lib64/libgdiplus.so.0(+0x34352)[0x7f403d9d5352]                                                 
/usr/lib64/libgdiplus.so.0(GdipCombineRegionRect+0xc8)[0x7f403d9d6b08]                               
/usr/lib64/libgdiplus.so.0(GdipCombineRegionRectI+0x4f)[0x7f403d9d6c7f]                              
[0x41868dd7]                                                                                         
======= Memory map: ========                                                                         
00400000-006e0000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 524278                             /usr/bin/mono               
008e0000-008e1000 r--p 002e0000 08:05 524278                             /usr/bin/mono               
008e1000-008ea000 rw-p 002e1000 08:05 524278                             /usr/bin/mono               
008ea000-00924000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                                              
00b9a000-04038000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
40027000-40038000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
400f2000-40103000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
401b0000-401d2000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
4023f000-40250000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
402f1000-40313000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
4039b000-403bd000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40495000-404a6000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
405fb000-4060c000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40627000-40638000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
4078e000-4079f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
407a4000-407b5000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40965000-40976000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40a6d000-40a7e000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40ad6000-40ae7000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40b52000-40b63000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40b7b000-40b8c000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40c35000-40c46000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40dda000-40deb000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40ebd000-40ece000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40ee1000-40ef2000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40f48000-40f49000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
40f49000-40f5a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
40fca000-40fdb000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
410f2000-410f3000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
411fa000-4120b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
4122f000-41240000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
412d3000-412e4000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
413ab000-413bc000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
413c4000-413d5000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41456000-41478000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
414a0000-414b1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41698000-416a9000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
416d3000-416e4000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
416f6000-41707000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41808000-41819000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41868000-4188a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
419b2000-419c3000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41ae8000-41af9000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41bc8000-41bd9000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41cc2000-41cd3000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41d75000-41d86000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41ddb000-41dec000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41e0c000-41e1d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41e91000-41ea2000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41ecd000-41ede000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41f41000-41f52000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41fbf000-41fd0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4028000000-7f402804b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f402804b000-7f402c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f402cf2e000-7f402cf32000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f402cf32000-7f402cf3b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f402cf3b000-7f402d653000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:23710]
7f402d653000-7f402d6f9000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 396413                     /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f402d6f9000-7f402d8f9000 ---p 000a6000 08:05 396413                     /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f402d8f9000-7f402d8fb000 r--p 000a6000 08:05 396413                     /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f402d8fb000-7f402d8fe000 rw-p 000a8000 08:05 396413                     /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f402d900000-7f402d910000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f402d910000-7f402d966000 r--p 00000000 08:05 397875                     /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.Services/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.Services.dll
7f402d966000-7f402d9ae000 r--p 00000000 08:05 397360                     /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
7f402d9ae000-7f402dfc6000 r--p 00000000 08:05 139939                     /home/smathers/Millennia/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
7f402dfc6000-7f402dfed000 r--p 00000000 08:05 139936                     /home/smathers/Millennia/System.Data.SQLite.dll
7f402dfed000-7f402e00f000 r--p 00000000 08:05 6198                       /usr/share/fonts/TTF/liberation/LiberationSans-BoldItalic.ttf
7f402e00f000-7f402e011000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 143210                     /lib64/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7f402e011000-7f402e210000 ---p 00002000 08:05 143210                     /lib64/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7f402e210000-7f402e211000 r--p 00001000 08:05 143210                     /lib64/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7f402e211000-7f402e212000 rw-p 00002000 08:05 143210                     /lib64/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7f402e214000-7f402eacd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f402eacd000-7f402eade000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 396211                     /usr/lib64/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
7f402eade000-7f402ecdd000 ---p 00011000 08:05 396211                     /usr/lib64/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
7f402ecdd000-7f402ecde000 r--p 00010000 08:05 396211                     /usr/lib64/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
7f402ecde000-7f402ecdf000 rw-p 00011000 08:05 396211                     /usr/lib64/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
7f402ecdf000-7f402ed44000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 395617                     /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10.0.4
7f402ed44000-7f402ef43000 ---p 00065000 08:05 395617                     /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10.0.4
7f402ef43000-7f402ef44000 r--p 00064000 08:05 395617                     /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10.0.4
7f402ef44000-7f402ef4d000 rw-p 00065000 08:05 395617                     /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10.0.4
7f402ef4d000-7f402ef5f000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 395791                     /usr/lib64/libhogweed.so.2.1
7f402ef5f000-7f402f15e000 ---p 00012000 08:05 395791                     /usr/lib64/libhogweed.so.2.1
7f402f15e000-7f402f15f000 r--p 00011000 08:05 395791                     /usr/lib64/libhogweed.so.2.1
7f402f15f000-7f402f160000 rw-p 00012000 08:05 395791                     /usr/lib64/libhogweed.so.2.1
7f402f160000-7f402f185000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 396140                     /usr/lib64/libnettle.so.4.3
7f402f185000-7f402f385000 ---p 00025000 08:05 396140                     /usr/lib64/libnettle.so.4.3
7f402f385000-7f402f386000 r--p 00025000 08:05 396140                     /usr/lib64/libnettle.so.4.3
7f402f386000-7f402f387000 rw-p 00026000 08:05 396140                     /usr/lib64/libnettle.so.4.3
7f402f387000-7f402f397000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 396445                     /usr/lib64/libtasn1.so.3.2.0
7f402f397000-7f402f596000 ---p 00010000 08:05 396445                     /usr/lib64/libtasn1.so.3.2.0
7f402f596000-7f402f597000 r--p 0000f000 08:05 396445                     /usr/lib64/libtasn1.so.3.2.0
7f402f597000-7f402f598000 rw-p 00010000 08:05 396445                     /usr/lib64/libtasn1.so.3.2.0
7f402f598000-7f402f5a0000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 395995                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7f402f5a0000-7f402f79f000 ---p 00008000 08:05 395995                     /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1Stacktrace:

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus.GdipCombineRegionRectI (intptr,System.Drawing.Rectangle&,System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CombineMode) <0xffffffff>
  at System.Drawing.Region.Exclude (System.Drawing.Rectangle) <0x00027>
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Region.Exclude (System.Drawing.Rectangle) <0xffffffff>
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control/DoubleBuffer.End (System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) <0x0016f>
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint (System.Windows.Forms.Message&) <0x0016f>
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message&) <0x001e7>
  at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message&) <0x00013>
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control/ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message&) <0x00024>
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control/ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message&) <0x00036>
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (intptr,System.Windows.Forms.Msg,intptr,intptr) <0x002bc>
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.DispatchMessage (System.Windows.Forms.MSG&) <0x0001f>
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.DispatchMessage (System.Windows.Forms.MSG&) <0x00024>
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunLoop (bool,System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext) <0x00c73>
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext) <0x0005f>
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (System.Windows.Forms.Form) <0x00033>
  at Millennia.Program.Main (string[]) <0x001c7>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

        mono() [0x491db2]
        /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xef70) [0x7f40407f1f70]
        /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x7f404048b245]
        /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x17b) [0x7f404048c7cb]
        /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x6d5be) [0x7f40404c45be]
        /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x73476) [0x7f40404ca476]
        /usr/lib64/libgdiplus.so.0(+0x34352) [0x7f403d9d5352]
        /usr/lib64/libgdiplus.so.0(GdipCombineRegionRect+0xc8) [0x7f403d9d6b08]
        /usr/lib64/libgdiplus.so.0(GdipCombineRegionRectI+0x4f) [0x7f403d9d6c7f]
        [0x41868dd7]

Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Comment: looks like you answered your own question. you compiled it, it didn't run, and has issues...

Comment: Are you sure that this program runs under MONO in any environment?  MONO is ***not*** a perfect replacement.

Comment: @BaileyS That's what have been hearing for the last 3 months from people online. I just trying to figure it out for myself. My program is bit complex. So, it basically runs for awhile and then it crashes.

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a very old bug in Mono that hasn't been closed out yet. It has to do with double buffering:

https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=446341

Comment: I do have double buffering property enabled for some of my winforms. If what you are saying is true, I have to re-write a lot of my code. OUCH!!!

Comment: @digitalanalog You'll note that in the exception call stack, you've got a call to WmPaint() which then calls Control/DoubleBuffer.End. This is why I brought up the double-buffering issue.

Comment: Pete you are absolutely correct. I just confirmed your answer. I simply ran my program without having those double-buffered winforms displayed or loaded and my program ran and ran without crashing for a long time. Then, I ran my program with one of the winform with double-buffered opened and within 10 minutes of running the program crashed with the exact above error message. At least now I know what the problem is. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, there's 2 parts:

1. Compiled on 32b, ran on 64b: That's no issue for .NET or mono
2. can you run a .NET compiled assembly on mono without problems ? : If your assembly does not P/Invoke and if it uses API implemented on mono, yes, it should run without problems. There's a tool http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA that can help you check if your app will run on mono

now, for your particular issue, look at what @Pete said.

Comment: My program does use few P/Invoke throughout my program.